# VBA Trying to navigate through webpages IE

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to automate a report.
The website does not have specific URL for different Tabs. I keep encountering errors I've tried using getelementsby ID and Classname but it isn't working.
This is my first time working with VBA and IE.

Errors encountered are 462 Remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable
Error not finding element ID

```
Sub openidp()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 
  With IE
    .navigate "http://idp/analytics/saw.dll?dashboard&PortalPath=%2Fshared%2F3.0%20Tenancy%20Management%2F_portal%2F3.0.4%20Area%20Manager%20Tenancy%20Toolkit"   
    'navigate to page
    Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE  'Wait until page finished loading
      DoEvents
    Loop  
  End With

newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + 15
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
Application.Wait waitTime  'allow time for username and password to be 
                           'added and for page to open up

Set element = IE.Document.getElementsByID("dashboard_page_10_tab").Click

Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  DoEvents
  Loop
End Sub
```

Html script from inspect element (not sure on how to make this look tidy)

```
table class="masterH3 masterTabBarTabSecondaryEnabled secondaryTabEnabled 
    tabContainer" 
    id="dashboard_page_10_tab" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td title="Monitors trends in the level of rent debt broken down
                by week or month">
                <div tabindex="0" title="Monitors trends in the level of 
                    rent debt broken down by week or month" 
                    style="margin-right: 1px; margin-left:1px;">
                    Debt
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table
```

Comment: Not sure if this works here because your page is not reachable. But you can try this `Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")` instead of this `Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`. Read here for more infos: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/ieinternals/default-integrity-level-and-automation

Comment: @Zwenn this isn't working the page doesn't open up any more

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Internet Explorer disconnects from VBA (In my case some internal security settings). The solution is to reconnect Internet Explorer to VBA:

Include this code after the line IE is not responsive anymore and the existing Internet Explorer window will be assigned to = IEObject1

```
Dim shellWins As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim explorer As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Set shellWins = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

For Each explorer In shellWins
    If explorer.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
        Set IEObject1 = explorer
        Debug.Print explorer.LocationURL
        Debug.Print explorer.LocationName
    End If
Next

Set shellWins = Nothing
Set explorer = Nothing
```

If you have several IE windows open then this code picks the last one. You can choose between the windows by using the URL or LocationName if you need several open windows.